# How to cite a video game in Bibtex

Tags: latex, bibtex

I am writing an essay on video games and naturally I am referencing a number of them as examples. Since we are in Computer Science, we use the IEEE reference style and there is a section that specifically shows [how should a computer game be referenced](http://wwwlib.murdoch.edu.au/find/citation/ieee.html#Other):

> [4] *The Hobbit: The prelude to the
>   Lord of the Rings*. [CD-ROM]. United
>   Kingdom: Vivendi Universal Games,
>   2003.

So what type of entity do I use in Bibtex and which fields do I set?

Note: I am using the IEEEtr bibliography style in latex.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`@MISC{hobbit,
   author = "Veivendi Universal Games",
   title = "The Hobbit: The Prelude to the Lord of the Rings",
   howpublished = "[CD-ROM]",
   year = 2003,
}`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using the `IEEEtran.bst` style, the current accepted answer will abbreviate the author's names. Although it still doesn't match the requested style in the Question, I use the following format:

```
@misc{game:hobbit,
    title         = "{T}he {H}obbit: {T}he {P}relude to the {L}ord of the {R}ings",
    organization  = "Vivendi Universal Games",
    location      = "United Kingdom",
    howpublished  = "[PC CD-ROM]",
    year          = "2003",
}
```

> [63] “The Hobbit: The Prelude to the Lord of the Rings,” [PC CD-ROM], Vivendi Universal Games, 2003

Note that in order to avoid changes in capitalisations, the necessary characters must be in `{}`. An easier solution is to stick the whole title in braces:

```
"{The Hobbit: The Prelude to the Lord of the Rings}",
```

This solution also leaves `author` open for games developed by individuals, e.g.:

```
@misc{game:redeclipse,
    author        = "Reeves, Quinton and Salzman, Lee",
    title         = "{R}ed {E}clipse",
    year          = "2011",
    note          = "v1.3.1",
    url           = "http://www.redeclipse.net",
}
```

As an aside, if you use the `url` field, `IEEEtran` automatically inserts an '[Online]':

> [62] Q. Reeves and L. Salzman, “Red Eclipse,” 2011, v1.3.1. [Online]. Available: http://www.redeclipse.net

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use a book or misc type? Books also have titles and publishers.
Just play a little with the different fields until the result suits you. The original Bibtex type can not be seen in the output file.

Regards
Nick